# WPF Radiobutton (two) (binding to boolean value)

Tags: wpf, binding, radio-button, boolean

I have a property of type boolean presented with checkbox.

I want to change that to two radiobuttons that bind on the same property presenting the value true/false.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1" 
             IsChecked="{Binding PropertyValue}" Content="Yes" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1"  Content="No" 
             IsChecked="{Binding PropertyValue, 
                         Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}}" />
```

```
public class BoolInverterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: For some reason I must use two different GroupNames. Otherwise, the boolean in the ViewModel can be set to true, but is never reset to false (even though the radio buttons appear to behave properly)

Comment: Hi, you are forgot "/" to close the second radio button.

Comment: @Ragunathan I'm getting an error: "The resource 'BoolInverterConverter' could not be resolved". Not sure how I can fix this: any ideas?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: you just need to add a Resources section

Comment: I placed this in child window. When I open first time child window it is good. When I close and open child window second time I get stack overflow exception since the converter is executing infinite number of times.

Comment: This does not work and causes many unnessary VM trigger...

Comment: Agree with Qwertie and others, tried this a number of times, does not work -- the logic looks correct, but as the bindings are executed, the button check states are not set to reflect it.

Comment: This solution does work if the GroupName is taken away for both of the RadioButtons. The GroupName property will cause inter-triggering thus causing the stack overflow. It took me a few days to find the root cause.

Answer (score 20):

The standard binding approach has the unfortunate side effect of firing the binding setter as "unselected" whenever the UI is loaded. So if you've got code to handle the user's clicks in the setter for your bool, it will do some weird stuff like fire the setter to "false" even though you've bound it to a "true" bool.

I got around this with a converter used specifically for radio buttons:

```
public class BoolRadioConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool Inverse { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool) value;

        return this.Inverse ? !boolValue : boolValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;

        if (!boolValue)
        {
            // We only care when the user clicks a radio button to select it.
            return null;
        }

        return !this.Inverse;
    }
}
```

In your resources:

```
<converters:BoolRadioConverter x:Key="BoolRadioConverter" />
<converters:BoolRadioConverter x:Key="InverseBoolRadioConverter" Inverse="True" />
```

In your xaml:

```
<RadioButton
    Content="True option"
    GroupName="radioGroup1"
    IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty,
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolRadioConverter}}" />
<RadioButton
    Content="False option"
    GroupName="radioGroup2"
    IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty,
                        Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolRadioConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Great! works as expected for my problem. Copied to put on my blog for future reference

Comment: and if I call it `InverseBoolRadioConverter` I could ignore the Inverse variable, and return true because I'll always use it as converter for radio buttons only.

Comment: I've found that your code works best for nullable booleans but you can adjust the if condition in the converter to handle non-nullable: if (!boolValue && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) != null)

Comment: Thank you! Faced the same problem and very glad I found your solution

Comment: Worked fine to me as soon as I recognized the radio buttons need to be located in different groups.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a value-converter that reverts the boolean value:

With that converter, bind one Checkbox.IsChecked-property to the boolean value without the converter and one CheckBox.IsChecked-property with the converter. This should do the trick.

Here the code for such a converter. I have copied it from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OppositeBoolConverter.aspx) and added some lines of code. There you will find more information about.

```
public class BoolToOppositeBoolConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
        }
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }
                    return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");
        }
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

To use it, declare it in the resource-section.

```
 <local:BoolToOppositeBoolConverter x:Key="BoolToOppositeBoolConverter_ValueConverter"/>
```

And the use it in the binding as a static resource:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourProperty}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourProperty,Converter={StaticResource BoolToOppositeBoolConverter_ValueConverter}}" />
```

Please note, the converter is only a simple example. Implement it neatly if you want to use it in productive code. I have not tested it. Make a comment if its not working.

Comment: thanx! i have used Ragunathan solution, but both work great. Speacialy i would like to thank you for your explanation and time inveted. Slowly im digging my way into WPF ...

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this without a converter if you set the GroupName property of two radio button to the same value (so only one can be checked at the time). Then, set IsChecked of one radio button to "True", and bind IsChecked of another to your Boolean. Switching radio buttons will change the Boolean value, however, changing the Boolean value to False will not check the other radio button.

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: This approach has a intermittent binding side effect if you show your dialog multiple times. I was able to work it around by cleaning the Data Context property before closing the dialog, so it looks like a framework issue to me. Regardless, I came up with a better solution that supports Boolean and enumerations, and works properly whether the GroupName property is set or not.

Comment: This is easiest and simplest solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution on how to bind radio buttons to any type (enumeration, Boolean, string, integer, etc.) with the sample code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720497/Binding-Radio-Buttons-to-a-Single-Property

Answer (score 2):

When using `MVVMLight` and `DataContext` is set in **XAML** as:

```
DataContext="{Binding <Your ViewModel property name>, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

`BoolInverterConverter` causes `Stack Overflow` second time the window gets opened.

The work around is to remove `DataContext` from XAML and do it in code in window constructor after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Your View Model class>();
```

After some testing it was not enough - Stack Overflow error could pop up randomly when clicking on radio button. The solution which worked for me - instead of the converter use another property for other radio button in a group:

```
public bool Is9to1 { get; set; }
public bool Is1to9 { get { return !Is9to1; } set { Is9to1 = !value; } }
```

in XAML:

```
   <RadioButton GroupName="Is9to1" IsChecked="{Binding Is1to9}"/>
   <RadioButton GroupName="Is9to1" IsChecked="{Binding Is9to1}"/>
```

Comment: Same issue here . I'm very new to WPF so I stopped researching why that happens.  Finally,  I use a custom converter with `CommandParameter` in XAML to avoid the SOE. Eg. `Yes` option with `CommandParameter=1`, `No` option with `CommandParameter=2`

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of [ragunathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375994/ragunathan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3361553/3895469).

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) =>
    Convert(value);

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) =>
    Convert(value);

private object Convert(object value) => 
    value is bool ? !(bool)value : value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little upgrade of RandomEngy's answer if you want your bool nullable (for no default value/Checked Radiobutton)

```
public class BoolRadioConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool Inverse { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? boolValue = (bool?)value;

        return this.Inverse ? !boolValue : boolValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? boolValue = (bool?)value;

        if (boolValue != null && (bool)!boolValue)
        {
            // We only care when the user clicks a radio button to select it.
            return null;
        }

        return !this.Inverse;
    }
}
```

and the rest is the same as his answer.

Answer (score 0):

From The answer of `Mr-RandomQC` everything works fine. But when I click another radio in the same group. Then the opposite radio will show a Red box around the radio button.

I changed the code a little bit from his answer to return `Binding.DoNothing` instead of return `null` like this.

```
public class BoolRadioConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool Inverse { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;

        return this.Inverse ? !boolValue : boolValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;

        if (!boolValue)
        {
            // Return Binding.DoNothing instead of Return null
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        return !this.Inverse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but weve been doing it like this for years, firstly with WPF now with WinUI 3

```
<StackPanel>

<TextBlock Text="Payment terms" />

<RadioButton
    x:Name="rdo_on_account"
    Content="Account"
    GroupName="account"
    IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsOnAccount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<RadioButton
    Content="Cash"
    GroupName="account"
    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=rdo_on_account, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolInvert}}" />
    
</StackPanel>



public class BoolInvert : IValueConverter
{
// convert the value to the destination format
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (value is bool)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //not a bool
    return value;
}

// convert from the destination format to the source format
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return value;
}
}
```