# WPF Showing a boolean with radiobuttons

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, stack-overflow, staticresource

I'm currently in the process of making an application that has some CRUD views. I wanted to show a boolean in one of my views for editing a row. I used this answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361362/wpf-radiobutton-two-binding-to-boolean-value) to try and solve this problem. I can edit the row once, if I try again I get a stackoverflow exception (whether I change to boolean value or not)

Resource declaration:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <bconv:BoolInverterConverter x:Key="BoolInverterConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Radio buttons:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Column="0" GroupName="istemplate"
                                 Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding Survey.isTemplate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" GroupName="istemplate"  Content="No" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Survey.isTemplate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}}" />
```

The item I'm trying to edit the boolean (isTemplate) of:

```
[Table("Survey")]
public class Survey : EntityBase
{
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User ConfirmedBy { get; set; }
    public Boolean isTemplate { get; set; }
    public Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

If I forgot to include some information please ask!

Comment: That should be a check box not a pair of radio buttons, where updating one calls the other leading to a cycle and the stack overflow

Comment: @sramalingam24 Except for the fact that the checkbox is inverted a.t.m. it does work, thanks :)

Comment: I just made a small program, using your code and the converter from the link you provided. It works as expected. Your exception is not in the code you provided. My guess is, it's in your ViewModel. When you break in the debugger, what does the call stack tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved thanks to @sramalingam24 comment

> That should be a check box not a pair of radio buttons, where updating one calls the other leading to a cycle and the stack overflow

The helper class I was using earlier can simply be deleted. All that's necessary is the CheckBox

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, so I want to share what I found.

**The reason is you are using GroupName**.

GroupName automatically reset the rest of radio-buttons.
It does trigger additional update property in viewModel.
And then you got StackOverflow exception since second radio-button update property with opposite value.

Not always possible replace radio buttons on checkBoxes. 
For example, in case if you will have one property bound via converter on more than 2 radio buttons.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Bound 2 radio buttons to the same boolean property (one with a invertedbooleanconverter) and as a habit, I had them as the same GroupName.

The Solution is exactly as @Anton suggests:  If you want to keep your view model unchanged simply remove the GroupName property on the RadioButtons.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverFlow Exception points to Recursively/Endlessly doing something.

I havent seen your code but, wild guess - Check the Setter of you Binding: Survey.isTemplate. Are you assigning the CLR property or the Bound property.

Ex:

```
private string _Name = null;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _Name;  // If you do return Name here - it will be overflow exception
    }
    set
    {
        _Name = value;  // If you do Name = value instead - it will be Overflow exception.
        NotifyPropertyChange("Name");
    }
}
```